# Some applications (Anki, Okular, Calibre) start very slowly

Tags: 12.04

When I start one of the applications mentioned in the title from the terminal, I get this:

```bash
Registered DEC:  true 
Error in contacting registry 
"org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply" 
"Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken." 
Could not query active accessibility event listeners. 
Registered event listener change listener:  true
```

Currently I am running 12.04
This problem started a couple of days ago, shortly after I've installed okular from within the software center.

by "slow" I mean it takes about 30 seconds. Other applications like chromium start instantly.

Comment: Is the Dbus daemon running?

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ yes, dbus-daemon is running 2 times.

Comment: Under what account? Your account? Or `root`?

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ both under my account, not root. I now tried running calibre with gksudo. In that case it starts as fast as it should.

Comment: more on those two processes: **1)** /bin/dbus-daemon -config-file=/etc/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-adress 3  **2.)** //bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session

Answer (score 1):

The problem disappeared by itself.
I have no idea why this is. Simply rebooting didn't do the trick.

Thanks @ObsessiveSSOℲ for trying to help!